# HTTP request and response flow for get

Tags: http, httpresponse, http-get, http-request

I am having difficulties understanding the HTTP request and response flow. I am working with a system where I can "hijack" incoming HTTP request and give my own response. The problem I am having is that some type of GET request seem to assume that all data is sent back in first request.

For instance, JPEG image requests, no matter the size (my tests include 0-20 MB JPEG files) seems to assume that the entire data is sent in the first response. Even if I don't send any data and explicitly set range header to 0 I never get a response back from the client asking for the data.

Other data request types, such as mp4 video, the client seems perfectly fine with getting a response with only header information with no data and then sends a new request explicitly asking for byte range 0-.

Is there some kind of agreement between the the client and server that some types should be sent back in one request while others can be split up in a number of requests?

Comment: Don't understand. It's client which *always* initializes the communication. Even if requesting for video this is still a single request and the response is streamed.

Comment: Well of course it is the client that initializes the communication, was not what I was asking about.

Comment: Surely someone knows here at stack overflow! :)

Comment: Probably someone knows, but it seems that you need to clarify your question.